# How to emulate window.location with React Router 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react SPA that is served by Laravel..
I want the SPA to be able to go to some pages that are also served by Laravel..

Update:

As an example...
in my coreui-react based app.. I want to allow the user to open the user manual which is built using vuepress. I want to be able to open it in a brand new page and not have it bundled into the SPA. The SPA shows up at https://test.local/ the user manual is at https://test.local/docs

Link to="/docs" flicks me back to the SPA, Link to="//test.local/docs" also as does

I've also tried placing onClick={() => window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/docs"} inside the Link but no change except that it does drop out of the local dev server (port 3000).. but if its in a build - then it still gets caught by the ReactRouter

There is a suggestion that StaticRouter would do it - but all the examples I see refer to server side rendering of content that the SPA will consume, not flicking you out to a server delivered page..

I'm kinda at my wits end.. my only thought at the moment is to move the SPA  from "/" to "/app" and and not handle "/" at all within the SPA with the hope that ReactRouter might let that through

This seems to be a long term issue in ReactRouter.. but in the past you could brute-force your way out with <a href or window.location - but seems no longer to be the case..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,
you can use "history":

```
const history = useHistory();
```

you have to import `useHistory` from `react-router-dom`:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
```

and then you can use:

```
history.push('/analytics')
```

Comment: So I guess I need to build a component to hold this?

Comment: You have to use routes in your app, are you using routes?

Comment: There are routes in both the SPA and laravel..  actually it looks like either 1. I have to direct "unknown" routes to laravel (possibly the best DRY method.. or handle the top level routes from laravel within the SPA directing them back... it used to be possible to simply use window.location but that seems not to work anymore

Comment: I'm thinking this might be the solution https://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2020/03/02/static-router-static-assets-serving-a-server-side-rendered-site/ but working it out will take some thinking..

Comment: the argly way might be to do an onClick action for th links I need to go out of the SPA and build the url using var full = window.location.origin + "path"

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147